# Chinese characters in SQL not shown in android

Tags: android, sql, unicode

I have a sql database of chinese characters which are utf8_unicode_ci. It works well with chrome on my laptop, however these characters will not shown on Chrome in my android device. I wonder whether the problem is the web-browser or my smartphone?

Comment: How does Chrome query the database?

Comment: im using php to fetch from database and then echo

Comment: Try other webbrowsers for your phone.